# Error on upload: "Impossible to create the root directory..."

Tags: assets, upload, volumes

In Craft 3.2.10, I'm getting this error message when I try to upload an image asset:

> Upload failed. The error message was: “Impossible to create the root
>   directory "/Users/me/Work/Client/repo/web/craftcms-assets/project-slide-photos". mkdir():
>   Permission denied”

I've made the permissions for `project-slide-photos` to 777 and 774, and likewise tried both for the parent directory. Is it trying to create a directory that's already there? I tried removing `project-slide-photos` also, and it still doesn't work.

What do I need to do to make my assets upload into this directory?

Edit: Wondering if using Docker Compose could have something to do with this:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: 'flipbox/php:72-apache'
        ports:
            - '80:80'
            - '443:443'

        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html/'
        environment:
            ENVIRONMENT: dev
            DB_SERVER: db
            DB_USER: craft
            DB_PASSWORD: craft
            DB_DATABASE: craft
            XDEBUG_ON: "yes"
            XDEBUG_HOST: "host.docker.internal"
            XDEBUG_IDEKEY: "PHPSTORM"
            APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: "/var/www/html/web"
    db:
        image: 'mysql:5.7'
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'

        volumes:
            # Location to import a database dump. 
            - ./src:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            # Location of the generated mysql files.
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: craft
            MYSQL_USER: craft
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: craft
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand now within the context of you are using docker. Since docker creates a new file system separate from your computer's file system, you will want to run these commands on the docker instance.

I do not use docker regularly, but I believe you can use `docker attach` while the droplet is running to access the droplet's file system.

You will want to set the parent folder to have higher privileges. Try this command:

```
chmod 774 craftcms-assets
```

Privileges are composed of three numbers: self, group, and world. There are also three access levels: read, write, and execute. 7 will give access to read, write, and execute. You will want to use 7 for your own commands (self) and for craft's commands (group), but not for the general public (world).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok I tried that, and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: it's the same error? can you make sure that the web and repo folders have 774 also

Comment: Hm. Yup, same error. Changed both of those, and it's still not working.

Comment: Realized Docker Compose could have something to do with it. Updated my question.

Comment: @BBaysinger I've updated my answer with docker information!

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the top result on Google for this error, I wanted to add that what fixed it for me (a non-docker user) was **setting the permissions for the "/assets/images" directory to 775**.

Craft's documentation says to set certain folders to 774, but evidently it needs that Public Execution permission for the system to recognize it.